# How to use the output state $\frac1{\sqrt2}(|0,f(0)\rangle+|1,f(1)\rangle)$ given by this quantum circuit?

Tags: quantum-gate, textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang

In Nielsen and Chuang, for the following circuit that demonstrates quantum parallelism, I have the following question:

[image]

since the output state of the circuit is
$$\frac1{\sqrt2}(|0,f(0)\rangle+|1,f(1)\rangle).$$

How would we isolate the state of f(0) and f(1) from the state of 0 and 1 to get information that we want (state of f(0) and f(1))?

Comment: Hi! Each post should be focused on *one* question. Ideally, it would also have a good title, which is easier when it asks one question :-)

Answer (score 3):

The idea is after only one application of $U_f$, the superposition state now contains **both** function values of $f(x)$ **entangled** to their corresponding input value $x$. This effect is called **quantum parallelism**.

This can be extend to more general cases, where the *data register* (the register at the top) has more than 1 qubit. Suppose the *data register* has $n$ qubits, then by first applying Hadamard gate to each of the qubit (so that each of the qubit starts in the state $\dfrac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$ then we have:

$$ U_f: \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}} \sum_{x =0}^{2^n -1} |x\rangle |0\rangle  \rightarrow   \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}} \sum_{x =0}^{2^n -1} |x\rangle |f(x)\rangle     $$

Note if you let $n = 1$ then you get back the form in your question:
$$ U_f: \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|0\rangle + |1\rangle \big)|0\rangle =  \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|0\rangle|0\rangle + |1\rangle |0\rangle \big) \rightarrow \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|0\rangle|f(0) \rangle + |1\rangle |f(1)\rangle \big)     $$

So the idea is that with just one application of $U_f$, which uses only $n$ qubits, you created a state that contains all of the $2^n$ function values $f(x)$ that are entangled with their corresponding input value $x$.

However, you are right that extracting out each value of $f(x)$ can be a problem. This is because we can only gain limited information from this superposition because of the **Holevo bound theorem**. That is, upon measurement in the computational basis, we will project the final state onto a single input/output pair $|x\rangle |f(x) \rangle$ randomly. So even though $2^n$ values of $f(x)$ appear in the superposition state, we still really need $2^n$ computations of $U_f$ to extract them all. This is why quantum parallelism is actually less powerful than we think. And in general, quantum parallelism and quantum computation don't just provide an exponential speed-up over classical computation. We must **carefully** designing the algorithm to take advantage of this parallelism.